# How to edit and save .docx file in winrar directly without extracting?

Tags: office365, winrar

I edit .docx file inside .rar file without extracting it. After saving and closing .docx, winrar popup this message:

[image]

Also opening .docx again, edited data is not saved. I need to extract the .docx file, edit it, and Add to archive back to .rar again.

How to edit .docx file in winrar directly without extracting?

I can edit and save .txt files inside winrar without even extracting it:

[image]

Softwares used here: Winrar 6.00 beta 1 (full version), Office 365.

Comment: `I edit .docx file inside .rar file without extracting it.` .. technically, no you don't.  The files are getting extracted to your temp directory.  There is currently no technology that I am aware of that allows you to edit a compressed file in memory only.. in fact.. that doesn't even make sense.  Compression requires looking at all of the bits of a file to decide where redundancy exists.. so sorry bruh.. no, this is not really possible.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I added about behavior of .txt files inside .rar file. Please fix my image link.

Comment: Fixed the image link.  You had a space after https.  The reason you are getting that message is probably because word still has an open *handle* to the file.  Believe it or not, a docx file is yet another zip file and closing the handles is complicated.  Word has to unzip the file (in temp) and after editing, button it all back up.  You can use the process explorer to see who is the actual culprit for keeping the file open but it is probably word itself.

Comment: Oh.. for fun.. UNZIP the docx file and you can see what parts make it happen.  Oh.. I am happy to help you (as we all are).. good luck figuring this out.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I added another image, please fix image link.

Comment: At this point, YOU fix the image link.  Remove the space between https and the forward slashes.  I don't need the points and I am certainly here to help, not work for someone.